# What makes NTDLL!_KiUserApcDispatcher jump to an address which doesn't belong to a module in a process?

Tags: windows, debugging, access-violation, crash-dumps

I'm debugging a crash dump which gets an Access Violation exception (0xC0000005). The AVE comes from jumping to an address that doesn't belong to any of the 2 loaded modules in the process:

[image: Call stack of Access Violation exception]
[image: Loaded modules in crashing process]

What would cause this so early in the process?

It appears that the process is mapping memory (`_ZwCreateSection`) to load a module... did the module fail to load in some way which `LoadLibrary` succeeds but the module isn't actually loaded?

Comment: The code is busy dispatching an exception.  When that bombs too then you conclude "totally corrupted process state".

Comment: The 2nd part of the callstack is dispatching, but what about the first part where it is, what I'm guessing, mapping an executable section?

Comment: Has any of your code started running at the point of the crash?  Assuming it has not I think the next diagnostic step is to use Process Monitor to examine file system and registry activity just before the crash.  Could perhaps be a DLL with a corrupted header, or something of that sort.  (Or could be corruption in the executable's format, I guess.)

Comment: I think it hasn't yet, but I'm not sure since I'm relying only on my understanding of process loading and execution on Windows. Procmon is a great suggestion since it does look like an external cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause for this behavior was an anti-virus software (Norton) hijacking the DLL load. Running [GFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/gflags) to [debug LoadLibrary](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2006/11/20/debugging-loadlibrary-failures/) showed that the mscorlib.dll library was being prevented from loading.